# Java consistent synchronization

Tags: java, spring, synchronization

We are facing the following problem in a Spring service, in a multi-threaded environment:

- three lists are freely and independently accessed for Read
- once in a while (every 5 minutes), they are all updated to new values. There are some dependencies between the lists, making that, for instance, the third one should not be read while the second one is being updated and the first one already has new values ; that would break the three lists consistency.

My initial idea is to make a container object having the three lists as properties.
Then the synchronization would be first on that object, then one by one on each of the three lists.

Some code is worth a thousands words... so here is a draft

```
    private class Sync {
        final List<Something> a = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Something>());
        final List<Something> b = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Something>());
        final List<Something> c = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Something>());
    }

    private Sync _sync = new Sync();

   ...

   void updateRunOnceEveryFiveMinutes() {
     final List<Something> newa = new ArrayList<Something>();
     final List<Something> newb = new ArrayList<Something>();
     final List<Something> newc = new ArrayList<Something>();

     ...building newa, newb and newc...

     synchronized(_sync) {

        synchronized(_sync.a) {
            _synch.a.clear();
            _synch.a.addAll(newa);
        }

        synchronized(_sync.b) { ...same with newb... }

        synchronized(_sync.c) { ...same with newc... }
   }

   // Next is accessed by clients

   public List<Something> getListA() {
      return _sync.a;
   }

   public List<Something> getListB() { ...same with b... }

   public List<Something> getListC() { ...same with c... }
```

The question would be,

- is this draft safe (no deadlock, data consistency)?
- would you have a better implementation suggestion for that specific problem?

*update*

Changed the order of _sync synchronization and newa... building.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your best option is to expose a "current state" object and use volatile, ditching all the synchronized code.  (also, you may want to make the lists unmodifiable wrappers just to be safe).

```
public class ListState {
  List final a;
  List final b;
  List final c;
}

private volatile ListState _state;

void updateRunOnceEveryFiveMinutes() {
  // generate new lists ...

  // re-assign current list state (e.g. atomically publish all your updates)
  _state = new ListState(newA, newB, newC);
}

public ListState getCurrentLists() {
  return _state;
}
```

Comment: +1 no need of thread synchronization, the volatile keyword prevents local thread caching, all lists will be provided to the clients in the same updated-state... sounds perfect! Unless a negative comment/warning or a better (really?) solution posted, this will be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit wasteful to build a new list only to copy it into another (final) list.

Consider using immutable lists and assigning the new list to `_sync.a`, `_sync.b` and `_sync.c` (having removed the `final` modifier from them) after building the list (in `updateRunOnceEveryFiveMinutes`.)

Also you are synchronizing on 4 different objects.  It would be simpler to synchronize on just one object (`_sync` or possibly a dedicated lock object) for each method call.

If the lists returned by `getListA` etc. are immutable you do also not need the calls to `Collections.synchronizedList`.

Comment: @finnw *wasteful to build a new list only to copy...* Actually the building of the lists (newa...) may take some time (and the synchronized would go down the "building newa"), the last copy is in order to reduce the locked time. *Changed comment* Please see the next one!

Comment: @finnw I don't think your solution works: the lists are returned to a client (return `_sync.a`). So the client may keep using it *while it is being updated*. This is why there is a 2nd level of synchronization, and the call to `Collections.synchronizedList()`.

Comment: @ring0, in that case the client should probably be manually synchronizing on the list while it iterates through it.  The fine-grained synchronization provided by `Collections.synchronizedList` only synchronizes single calls, which may not be sufficient.

Comment: @finnw Collections.synchronizedList will prevent an empty or incomplete list to be accessed during its update. Thus the lock will only be active during the update, thanks to the 2nd level of sync. There is no need to add extra synchronization *client side* as it would slow down the program and have no extra value.

Comment: @ring0, what if a thread starts iterating through a list (without locking it) and after it has read half the elements the update begins?  The reading thread will block, but once the update has finished the reading thread will attempt to read the "remainder" of the list, but if the list size has changed it will throw an exception or see duplicates (because elements it previously read have moved further up the array.)  You cannot avoid this by synchronizing only in the update thread.   As I said, synchronizing the whole loop will solve it, and taking an immutable snapshot will solve it.

Comment: @finnw This is correct, if there is an iterator-ish access to the list while it is updated in this implementation, an exception would be thrown on the thread that iterates.

Answer (score 1):

The draft doesn't accomplish your objective. There is nothing here that prevents access to the old C while the new A or B are being computed. The simplest way to accomplish that is like so:

```
synchronized (a) {
  synchronized (b) {
    synchronized (c) {
    }
  }
}
```

around all accesses whether read or write. And I wouldn't do clear() and addAll(), just change the variable value to newA/newB/newC, although that would require some adjustment to the above.

Comment: I wanted to avoid that structure, due to the risk of a deadlock. If there is no ideal solution, maybe an idea would be to cope with a trade-off, having the infrequent event of one thread using new A and another one old B, the client code would be adapted appropriately (still a draft).

Comment: @ring0: There is no risk of a deadlock with that structure. Deadlock can only arise if you did the sync's in a different order anywhere.

Comment: I wouldn't want to build a structure like this one (at least avoid it as much as possible), but you are right in the current draft - and of course you cannot guess what it'll become in the future. So you got your +1 :-)

Comment: @ring0: I don't know *why* you wouldn't want to build a structure like this one, nor what 'in the current draft' is supposed to mean here. I am right not just 'in the current draft' but in all situations where you always claim locks in the same order. There is no possibility of deadlock when you do that. Period.

Comment: The project is pretty big, and that new part is likely to have extended features/role (for instance there are more than 3 properties, not only arrays / complex data structure...), shared by a team of programmers. Technically this will not deadlock in the draft case, but in a more general/generic approach I try to avoid a scheme that has nested objects synchronization - objects used throughout the application in the future. `jtahlborn` brought the ideal approach in this regard.